# Have 'Heading 4' keep with next, if next is 'Heading 5', but not in other instances

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I've got a Word document which is a rule book. To get the enumeration done, for different levels in the rules (rule 1, section 3, article 4, subarticle b, subsubarticle 1 etc.) different headings are used. This works great.

Sometimes subarticle c introduces a list containing of multiple subsubarticles. So far so good.

But sometimes, said subarticle c is the last line on the page, which means the list of subsubarticles starts on the first line of the next page. That's not good.

I also can't make Headings 4, 5 and 6 to **always** *Keep with next*, because then Heading 5 would also *keep with next* if the next paragraph isn't a list, bumping too much text to the next page, and wasting space.

My workaround up until now has been to take a look at all the bottoms of all the pages, and manually add "keep with next" to the "paragraph" (in Dutch  it's "Alinea") settings if I catch them. But since the document is 400+ p., this is not sustainable.

I found a macro somewhere (thanks and kudos!) which helps me a bit:

```
Sub ColonParaEnd_SetKeepWithNext()

    '=========================
    'Macro created 2010 by Lene Fredborg, DocTools - www.thedoctools.com
    'THIS MACRO IS COPYRIGHT. YOU ARE WELCOME TO USE THE MACRO BUT YOU MUST KEEP THE LINE ABOVE.
    'YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED TO PUBLISH THE MACRO AS YOUR OWN, IN WHOLE OR IN PART.
    '=========================
    'The macro iterates through all paragraphs in the active document
    'If a paragraph ends with a colon, Keep with next is applied
    '=========================

    Dim oPara As Paragraph
    Dim n As Long 'used as counter
    
    n = 0
    
    'Iterate though all paragraphs
    For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        With oPara
            'If a colon is found immediately before the paragraph mark, Chr(13), apply Keep with next
            'In case of end of a table cell, the end of cell marker is Chr(13) & Chr(7) - alså handle this
            If Right(.Range.Text, 2) = ":" & Chr(13) Or Right(.Range.Text, 3) = ":" & Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
                .Range.ParagraphFormat.KeepWithNext = True
                n = n + 1
            End If
        End With
    Next oPara
    
    MsgBox "Finished." & vbCr & "Keep with next applied to " & n & " paragraph(s).", vbOKOnly, "Apply Keep With next"
End Sub
```

**I was therefore wondering whether smart guys couldn't help me with a clever macro (possibly building on the one I quoted). What I am looking for:**

1. **If Heading 4 is followed by Heading 5, make this instance of Heading 4 "keep with next".**
2. **If Heading 5 is followed by Heading 6, make this instance of Heading 5 "keep with next".**
3. **If Heading 6 is followed by Heading 7, make this instance of Heading 6 "keep with next".**

Thanks in advance for your insight!